# Creating a Client Spring Security OAuth2 Applicaiton

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have the following architecture in my project:

```
 JOB_SCHEDULE ---> API A  ---> API B
```

My JOB_SCHEDULE call API A without any authentication and this is ok for us. But API A need to call API B, and this last have a client_credentials authentication.

We have a IdentityServer to generate this tokens, so in **API A** I configured the following:

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id=clientid
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=secret
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize
security.oauth2.client.grant-type=client_credentials
security.oauth2.client.authentication-scheme=form
```

And in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

And i have a endpoint in **API A** that call API B, see:

```
private final OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/sayhello")
    public ResponseEntity<String> redirectToResourceServer() {
        String strReturn = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9090/noscope", String.class);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(strReturn);
    }
```

But everytime I call `http://localhost/api/v1/hello/sayhello` I'm redirected to login page, but this is client_credentials I should not be redirected.

Comment: Run the applications with spring security in debug logging and the logs will tell you exactly what is failing

Comment: It looks like you are using the old OAuth2 dependencies which are in maintenance mode. Try using `spring-security-oauth2-client` in `org.springframework.security` instead. See more info here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-security-oauth2-client